# I am trying to implement a ReverseAnimation (hero animation) in my pageview possibly without using external packages

Tags: flutter

I have a pageview with 6 pages. In each of these there is the app logo (a png enclosed by hero). I need that, although it is a pageview and the Navigator is not called, the animation is a ReverseAnimation.

I have read that you can use the "coast" package, but I am not able to implement it and, to be honest, I would like to minimize the use of packages.

[image: What do I have now]
[image: The result I want]

I apologize for the bad quality of the gifs but I had to compress the files.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not what you want to hear but I Must say, without using the "coast" package or something similar, implementing what you want is exceedingly difficult. that's exactly why there are packages in the first place. if you faced problems with implementing that package, please post that problem instead.

Comment: The fact is that the packages I found don't allow me to have so much customization. I will modify the question by posting the video of how I would like the work to come and where I am now. Please take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: As promised, I changed the question. I hope now what I want to achieve is clearer. At this point I am also happy to use packages, the important thing is to get a result similar to what I want.

Comment: @THEMANUX you could transform the image size and change the widget beneath it or you can archive a similar effect by using 2 screens with Hero widget and changing the page transition animation to fade. put both images in same hero tag.